# Zipping Directory with Pigz Issue

Tags: zip, tar

I am trying to zip a directory with Pigz utilizing it's multi core compression. I'm not necessarily trying to compress, but simply speed up the process of zipping files.

The issue I've come across is that once Pigz is complete, tar archives all files into a single tar inside the zipped file. Is there any way to zip all of these files in the directory, into 1 zip, (each file individually) without having a single tar file?